# 16-bit MS-DOS Subsystem: csrss.exe

Tags: windows-xp, virus, sp3, ntvdm

I just booted up my Samsung N120 netbook (with Windows XP Home SP3) and a dialog box came up with a command prompt window behind it. The dialog box is titled `16 bit MS-DOS Subsystem` and the message is as follows:

`C:\DOCUME~1\SAMSUNG\csrss.exe The NTVDM CPU has encountered an illegal instruction. CS:0544 IP:0117 OP:63 00 64 00 34 Choose 'Close' to terminate the application.`

This only started on my most recent boot-up. One thing to note is that when I downloaded the Dropbox installer and opened it up, Panda Cloud Antivirus detected a suspicious file, which was `csrss.exe` and "neutralized it." However, an actual virus or trojan was not detected immediately before the file was detected and neutralized.

Just under two weeks ago, a trojan and two viruses were detected for some odd reason. (I only went to website I knew and I do not torrent or browse adult sites.) Anyhow, the two viruses came up in temporary files and the trojan was "neutralized."

Anyways, the main question is: **How can I repair the csrss.exe file such that Windows XP starts up properly?**

A screenshot could be posted upon request. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:** Well... it appears that Panda Cloud actually took the beating. AVG detected it and Panda has got to go.

**EDIT2:** After doing a search for "csrss" the only entry that came up was the one in  C:\WINDOWS\system32. I've run `sfc /scannow` but my XP disc doesn't work with it -- *UPDATE: I just realized that I'm using an XP Pro SP3 disc when my netbook was preinstalled with XP Home SP3... and I don't have the original installation disc, clearly* -- so I can't get the extra DLLs for the scan...

**EDIT3:** I just used Google to search up anything I could about this issue and this [link](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-888-c-windows-config-csrss-exe) suggests that I do some registry modifications... does this actually fix `csrss.exe` or does it just prevent it from starting in the first place?

**EDIT4:** I read the page which is linked above and have seemed to find an entry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`. There is a String in there called `Taskman` whose value is `C:\Documents and Settings\SAMSUNG\csrss.exe`. I am going to see what the actual value is supposed to be. *UPDATE: I referenced a clean machine to see what the proper value of Taskman is supposed to be. It turns out `Taskman` has the same value on another machine. I'm somewhat stumped.*

**SOLUTION POSTED IN MY ANSWER!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this was the solution:

Firstly, there were the basic antivirus software scans to determine any remaining threats on the computer. Using two different AV softwares was useful as my original AV software was infected.

Secondly, Most answers thought that the vital Windows application `csrss.exe` was not supposed to exist anywhere else but in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\`. However, `csrss.exe` actually exists as a completely hidden file under the user's folder in `C:\Documents and Settings\USER\`.

The system32 version of the file was unharmed, but it was the file in the user folder that was causing a dialog box to pop up on startup. The simple solution was to copy a clean copy from another machine and to copy and paste it into the user folder, even though it is not actually visible.

Thanks to others for their help!

Answer (score 2):

From the message I see that the csrss.exe mentioned is under `c:\docume~1\samsung`. This file should not be there, but under `c:\windows\system32`.

Check to see if there's still a (hopefully untouched) version of that file in your system32 folder. If that is the case, you can just delete the one under you documents folder.

You might have to boot with a bootable CD and delete the file from there as it will probably be in use.

Comment: The copy running from `C:\Docume~1\Samsung` is most likely some kind of malware.  The asker might want to run a good virus scanner from a bootable CD/USB drive to make sure that his system is really clean.

Comment: @afrazier: Thanks. Panda was infected and I'm using Microsoft Security Essentials now.

Answer (score 1):

`csrss.exe` is a [vital component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client/Server_Runtime_Subsystem) of a Windows installation. The best thing to do would be to open a `cmd` prompt (<kbd>start</kbd> -> <kbd>run</kbd>, type `cmd` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>) and type `sfc /scannow`. This will invoke the Windows System File Checker, which will scan and ensure all files are present and working. When it hits `csrss.exe`, it should restore it from its cache, or prompt you to insert your Windows disc (being a netbook, if it doesn't have a CD drive, you can use an external USB one, or a Windows installer USB drive). That should restore `csrss.exe` in the proper place for you.

Comment: +1 Didn't think of the `sfc /scannow` option. Watch out with that one though. I've seen systems where even the cache from the System File Checker was infected, so running that command actually placed the virus back!

Comment: It happens sometimes. But I usually tell people who get viruses/trojans/other infections that the only true way to make sure it's gone is to format & reinstall the operating system (maybe too harsh an answer for this question).

Comment: @thepurplepixel: That's exactly what I do.

Comment: @thepurplepixel: I want to avoid a reformat on this netbook, as the manufacturer has many preset configurations that I don't want to mess with. However I will do it if I can't fix this...

Comment: @Wesley: Exactly, that's why I answered with the `sfc` option instead of *just reformat it*. Hope you get a quick & easy solution!

Comment: @thepurplepixel: Unfortunately I don't have an XP Home SP3 disc... I just run the scan without using my disc at all... don't know if that is of any use...

Comment: @Wesley: it should restore it from the built-in DLL cache; you shouldn't need your disc unless it's corrupted in the DLL cache too. Even then, there are ways of getting it from Microsoft without a disc.

Comment: `"Even then, there are ways of getting it from Microsoft without a disc."`

@thepurplepixel: What does that mean? Also, Microsoft Security Essentials still detected something... have yet to see what it is...

Comment: @Wesley: Most easily, copying it off a working system. Or finding someone with a Windows disc. Or downloading a clean, working ISO of the installation disc and extracting it off there. Tons of ways. (If need be, I can extract the file off my Windows disc and email it to you).

Comment: @thepurplepixel: I've got several clean XP machines and I copied csrss.exe from one. However, I'm not too sure how I can replace the current one on my netbook... I can't end the process because it is always in use...

Comment: @Wesley: I generally use [MoveOnBoot](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/MoveOnBoot.shtml) (or equivalent) for that kind of thing.

Comment: @thepurplepixel: I used that to rename the current csrss.exe to csrss.old and copied a fresh csrss.exe to the system32 folder. Still, the dialog box pops up.

After looking into `C:\Documents and Settings\SAMSUNG\csrss.exe` it doesn't seem to exist even when hidden files/folders are enabled. Did the virus change the boot path for csrss.exe?

Comment: @Wesley: To be completely honest, I have no idea. Do you know what virus it was?

Comment: @thepurplepixel: I actually don't know, after removing Panda Cloud.